# painterResource is not receiving the parameter with the image kotlin multiplataform

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to deploy Moko Resource to share images between platforms, I'm using Kotlin Multiplatform.

After making all the settings and trying to enter the image path I receive an error message: "No value passed for parameter 'res'".

Below is a snippet of the code:

The error appears in "id = SharedRes.images.house_01"

```
Image(
          painter = painterResource(id = SharedRes.images.house_01),
          contentDescription = null,
          contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
     )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDJ7V.png)

Follow build.gradle (:shared)

```
//MOKO shared
multiplatformResources {
    multiplatformResourcesPackage = "com.module"
    multiplatformResourcesClassName = "SharedRes"
}
```

And SharedRes generated by Moko:

```
public expect object SharedRes {
  public object strings : ResourceContainer<StringResource>

  public object plurals : ResourceContainer<PluralsResource>

  public object images : ResourceContainer<ImageResource> {
    public val house_01: ImageResource
  }

  public object fonts : ResourceContainer<FontResource>

  public object files : ResourceContainer<FileResource>

  public object colors : ResourceContainer<ColorResource>

  public object assets : ResourceContainer<AssetResource>
}
```

If I don't pass it as an id, the message below appears:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwt5J.png)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using the answer to this question: [Kotlin Multiplatform ~ Add images on Android and Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74902818/kotlin-multiplatform-add-images-on-android-and-desktop)

I added the Resources files in commonMain, androidMain and desktopMain

The difference is that I needed to add @Composable to this expect function, as it gave an error in the current one in androidMain and desktopMain

commonMain

```
package com.domain.project

import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter
import dev.icerock.moko.resources.ImageResource

expect fun painterResource(imageResource: ImageResource): Painter
```

Here I reduced the return expression
androidMain

```
package com.domain.project

import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter
import dev.icerock.moko.resources.ImageResource

@Composable
actual fun painterResource(imageResource: ImageResource): Painter {
     return painterResource(id = imageResource.drawableResId)
}
```

Here it remained
desktopMain

```
package com.domain.project

import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.toPainter
import dev.icerock.moko.resources.ImageResource

@Composable
actual fun painterResource(imageResource: ImageResource): Painter {
     return imageResource.image.toPainter()
}
```

This way I didn't get an error message when calling the image

```
Image(
      painter = painterResource(MR.images.MyImage),
      contentDescription = "Some Description"
     )
```

Comment: got this error adding @ Composable in androidMain:
Mismatched @Composable annotation between expect and actual declaration